# android & facebook sdk - post a simple text to wall

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, share

What I want to do is posting a simple text to wall with the facebook sdk in android studio.
I want to post the text without the need of the Facebook app by the user.
Is that possible?

I've read
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share

And I have 2 problems.

1) How can I set the text of my share?

```
   FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
            .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
            .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

I can't see any setText method..or something like that..

Also can I do this without the facebook app installed on my phone?

I get the error

```
Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
```

I don't want to force my users to have facebook installed.. what should I do ?

Comment: see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#publishing

Comment: you can´t and shouldn´t set your own text, the message must be 100% user generated.

Comment: so if i want to post a text on wall , simple text, what should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

`Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider`

This can happen due to the following reasons:

1. You are not connected to internet
2. You have not given permission for internet access ( Manifest.xml)
3. You have not used a correct [hashkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13488560/1441326) for the app
4. You did not provide a correct App Id
5. You have not installed Facebook in your device

Check if you have added the permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
```

**EDIT:**
You can use `setName(String)` to set the title and `setDescription(String)` to set the description. take a look at this [documentation link.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.7/class/FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder/)

Comment: I already know why i have the problem, is 5.. read my question again

Comment: by _"How can I set the text of my share"_ you mean you want to have a custom title for your `FacebookDialog` ?

Comment: FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
                .setApplicationName("Excuse Me").setCaption("LALALA").setDescription("asda").setName("neim")
                .build();
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());  this will crash my app if I don't have facebook installed and if i have it will open a empty post dialog on facebook, without any text, just 'what's in your mind' ...

Comment: error about what? is not working without facebook sdk with this method. this is the problem.. Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message

Comment: _"I want to post the text without the need of the Facebook app by the user"_ i dont think its possible

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62114/discussion-between-boldijar-paul-and-sagar-pilkhwal).

Answer (score 1):

add permissions  in manifest of your application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP"/>
```

Comment: I have thoose already.. i've asked 2 things, how can I share a text with facebook sdk without the app installed, and how to share just a text, my code will share a link

Comment: shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Free education for all! http://linkd.in/xU8mCc");
startActivity(shareIntent);

Comment: @Partizio i don't want to share a link man, i want to share a text, is it that hard to understand ?

Comment: @Paul ve u got any solution.i need to share just text.

Comment: @SrishtiRoy I think I got, but this was too long ago and I don't remember how I did.